# How to find specific characters in a string and replace them with values fetched from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have text  stored in the table "StructureStrings"

```
Create Table StructureStrings(Id INT Primary Key,String nvarchar(4000))
```

**Sample Data**:

Id String
1  Select * from  Employee where Id BETWEEN ### and ### and Customer Id> ###
2  Select * from  Customer where Id BETWEEN ### and ###
3  Select * from  Department where Id=###

and I want to replace the "###" word with a values fetched from another table
named  "StructureValues"

```
 Create Table StructureValues (Id INT Primary Key,Value nvarcrhar(255))
        Id Value 
        1  33
        2  20
        3  44
```

I want to replace the "###" token present in the strings like

```
      Select * from  Employee where Id BETWEEN 33 and 20 and Customer Id> 44
      Select * from  Customer where Id BETWEEN 33 and 20
      Select * from  Department where Id=33
```

PS: 1. Here an assumption is that the values will be replaced with the tokens in the same order i.e first occurence of "###" will be replaced by first value of
"StructureValues.Value"  column and so on.

Comment: can we **safely** assume `nvarchar(40000)` is `nvarchar(4000)`?  `nvarchar(40000)` is an invalid data type.

Comment: @Larnu Yes infact its 4000 , thanks for the info, I have edited the question

Comment: With the latest edit, this is now impossible; or at least if there is the performance will be horrific. Especially with the use the replacement string `'###'` This means that there are an indeterminable amount of parameters, and they could be **any** data type. You need to seriously reconsider your set up. There also seem to now be no relationship between Ids. Unless `Select * from  Employee where Name like '%###%'` will be replaced to `Select * from  Employee where Name like '%44%'` (what employee would have a name with digits in..?)? If so, what is the string value for Id 4?

Comment: @Larnu apologies for bad db design, I think I will keep the number and the text values in separate tables

Comment: There's still not any kind of obvious relationship though. Why does Id 1 in `StructureStrings` relate to Ids `1` and `2` in `NumberStructureValues`? Why does Id 3 in `StructureStrings` relate to Ids `4` and then `2` (in THAT order...?) in the table `TextStructureValues`. How does 3 become 4 and then 2..? There is **NO** relationship here. Your data needs a to be able to relate to get the answer you want. if you can't relate the data, the task is impossible.

Comment: Hi @Larnu I just consulted with one of the devs here in my team and the only task he wants to achieve is  to replace the number of "###" tokens with the supplied values.

Comment: What Supplied values? Can you edit your post to show us how you want to use this is?

Comment: @Larnu Edited the post please see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162091/discussion-between-larnu-and-siddharth-bharadwaj).

Comment: I asked **how** you want to use this. I can't keep on repeating myself, but I'll do it anyway: "There's still not any kind of obvious relationship". Thus, if there is no obviously relationship, how are you expecting to build a relationship to know which values should be replaced. you must have an idea on what steps you're want to take. The closest, at the moment, I can get is still my answer below, and that falls over very quickly.

Comment: @Larnu
currently lets not get concerned about the realtionship
the only thing I want to achieve is to find the number of "###" tokens and replace them with the dv values
if there are three "###" tokens in the string , replace them with the top 3 values from the dv table
if there are two "###" tokens replace them with 2 top values from the dv table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a new answer, rather than editting my previous.

This uses [Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/); it does not use the built in splitter available in SQL Server 2016 onwards, as it does not provide an item number (thus no join criteria).

You'll need to firstly put the function on your server, then you'll be able to use this. DO NOT expect it to perform well. There's a lot of `REPLACE` in this, which will hinder performance.

```
SELECT (SELECT REPLACE(DS.Item, '###', CONVERT(nvarchar(100), SV.[Value]))
        FROM StructureStrings sq
             CROSS APPLY DelimitedSplit8K (REPLACE(sq.String,'###','###|'), '|') DS --NOTE this uses a varchar, not an nvarchar, you may need to change this if you really have Unicode characters
             JOIN StructureValues SV ON DS.ItemNumber = SV.Id
        WHERE SS.Id = sq.id
        FOR XML PATH ('')) AS NewString
FROM StructureStrings SS;
```

If you have any question, please place the comments on this answer; do not put them under the question which has already become quite a long discussion.

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted Thanks Larnu.

Comment: I have implemented this solution but somehow the "AND" operator is getting omitted ex :SELECT * FROM UAA_AUDIT_DETAILS WHERE  CATEGORY_ID = 1 AND TIME_STAMP BETWEEN #23:00#04:00

Answer (score 0):

Very different take here:

```
CREATE TABLE StructureStrings(Id int PRIMARY KEY,String nvarchar(4000));

INSERT INTO StructureStrings
VALUES (1,'SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Id BETWEEN ### AND ###'),
       (2,'SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Id BETWEEN ### AND ###');

CREATE TABLE StructureValues (Id int, [Value] int);
INSERT INTO StructureValues
VALUES (1,10),
       (2,20);
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000);
--I'm asuming that as you gave one output you are supplying an ID or something?
DECLARE @Id int = 1;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SS.Id,
           SS.String,
           SV.[Value],
           LEAD([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY SV.Id) AS NextValue,
           STUFF(SS.String,PATINDEX('%###%',SS.String),3,CONVERT(varchar(10),[Value])) AS ReplacedString
    FROM StructureStrings SS
         JOIN StructureValues SV ON SS.Id = SV.Id)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF(ReplacedString,PATINDEX('%###%',ReplacedString),3,CONVERT(varchar(10),NextValue))
FROM CTE
WHERE Id = @Id;

PRINT @SQL;
--EXEC (@SQL); --yes, I should really be using sp_executesql

GO
DROP TABLE StructureValues;
DROP TABLE StructureStrings;
```

*Edit: Note that Id 2 will return `NULL`, as there isn't a value to `LEAD` to. If this needs to change, we'll need more logic on what the value should be if there is not value to `LEAD` to.*

*Edit 2: This was based on the OP's original post, not what he puts it as later. As it currently stands, it's impossible.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (Id int)
DECLARE @StructureValues  TABLE (Id int, Value int)

INSERT INTO @Employee
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (10), (15), (20), (21)

INSERT INTO @StructureValues
VALUES (1, 10), (2, 20)

SELECT * 
FROM @Employee 
WHERE Id BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(Value) FROM @StructureValues) AND (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM @StructureValues)
```

Comment: @SiddharthBharadwaj If this is not correct, tell me your exact input and the exact output you want. Because it's currently unclear exactly what you are looking to do.